# Migration Error in django based application

Tags: postgresql, python-3.6, django-2.2

I setuped an existing application with upgrade in django and python version. 
Upgraded - Django2.2.3 & python3.7

Traceback Error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in 
execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 87, in handle
loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
self.build_graph()
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
raise exc
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
self.graph.validate_consistency()
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
[n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
[n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
File "/home/gaurav/Desktop/clk Update As of Sept 26/HOTFIX Update-1/clk/tenenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration main.0031_auto_20190716_1425 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('query_store', '0040_auto_20190624_1542')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if all your migration files are correct and nothing is missing out. Your traceback error is saying that in your main app 0031_auto_20190716_1425 migration file has dependencies on migration file 0040_auto_20190624_1542 of query_store app.

There are two solutions to this error:

1. If the migration file is missing then you need to recreate migration file manually.

Caution : Below solution will only work if you can recreate your db schema again by deleting the old schema.This will delete all your db data.

2. You can delete all migration files and run command "./manage.py makemigrations" to create migration files and"./manage.py migrate" to apply migrations on your db.